# update single row from model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, activerecord

I'm trying loop through records in my model and update their serial numbers. According to the tempArray all the values should be in order but the updating part isn't happening. Are there restrictions to using read/set/save in model or what am I missing?

```
    $tempArray['highest serial'] = $highest['Paragraph']['serial_number'];
    for( $i=$paragraph['Paragraph']['serial_number']; $i<$highest['Paragraph']['serial_number']; $i++ ){
        $current = $this->find('first', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Paragraph.id',
                'Paragraph.serial_number'
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Paragraph.webpage_id' => $paragraph['Paragraph']['webpage_id'],
                'Paragraph.list_element' => $paragraph['Paragraph']['list_element'],
                'Paragraph.serial_number' => ($i + 1)
            )
        ));
        $tempArray['i ' . $i . ' id'] = $current['Paragraph']['id'];
        $tempArray['i ' . $i . ' serial'] = $current['Paragraph']['serial_number'];
        $this->create($current);
        // $this->read('serial_number', $current['Paragraph']['id']);
        // $this->id = $current['Paragraph']['id'];
        $this->set('serial_number', $i);
        $this->save();
    }
    return $tempArray;
```

While the output from tempArray is `( [highest serial] => 2 [i 1 id] => 7 [i 1 serial] => 2 )` the serial_number of the record with `id=7` is not updated.

Haelp!

Edit: Changed read() into create() as suggested. No SQL or PHP errors occur, and tempArray values are correct, but no changes updated to database record. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit2: IT'S WORKING! Finally.. For some reason I only managed to get it working using saveField()

```
    for( $i=$paragraph['Paragraph']['serial_number']; $i<getHighestSerial($paragraph); $i++ ){
        $current = $this->find('first', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Paragraph.id',
                'Paragraph.serial_number'
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Paragraph.webpage_id' => $paragraph['Paragraph']['webpage_id'],
                'Paragraph.list_element' => $paragraph['Paragraph']['list_element'],
                'Paragraph.serial_number' => ($i + 1)
            )
        ));         
        $this->id = $current['Paragraph']['id'];
        $this->saveField('serial_number', $i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array)

> When calling save in a loop, don’t forget to call [create()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array).

Comment: Well, it should rather read: "**ALWAYS call create() when creating a new record.**"...

Comment: @mark - yah?  I didn't know that.  Can you clarify the reasoning?

Comment: Not only for the above reason (where you then easily forget it), but also, because you never know if any callback earlier already set the id, thus updating instead of creating the record. So it is not only good practice but pretty much a requirement to always add create() when creating.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, mark - will certainly start doing that :)

Comment: Changed it into the following but it still doesn't work. Thanks for the link though. $this->create($current); $this->set('serial_number', $i); $this->save();

Comment: @supafabulous - don't suppose you actually read the documentation in the book regarding `create();`?  (doesn't appear you have)